# Fetch block from external ctp file

Tags: cakephp, view, block, cakephp-2.1

I read [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html) and [this](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/view-inheritance-in-cakephp).
But i couldn't find the answer.

I have this file, where my action's views exist:
**View/MyController/index.ctp**

I also have this file
**View/Commons/blocks.ctp**

**Blocks.ctp** file includes these:

```
$this->start('sidebar1');
echo 'Some content';
$this->end();

$this->start('sidebar2');
echo 'Some content more';
$this->end();
```

---

So in the "**index.ctp**" file i want to fetch **sidebar1** or **sidebar2**.
How can i do this?
I wrote this to **index.ctp**, but didn't work.

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('sidebar1'); ?>
```

Also this one didn't work

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('../View/Commons/blocks.ctp/sidebar1'); ?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Any reason you're not using elements? Elements can be cached separately too.

Comment: @Costa thank you for reply. I'm a beginner so i'm not aware of differences between "view blocks" and "elements". I suppose "view blocks" are new in version 2.1 but elements exist for a long time. Their usage seems similar, but what are the differences between echo an element or fetch a block? Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put at top of your index.ctp:

```
$this->extend('Common/blocks.ctp');
```

With blocks and view inheritence, you can create "sub layouts" which are basically analogous to the standard Cake layout file.  So you'd have the main layout.ctp, and the controller-action view ctp would be based on a parent view file (e.g. /Commons/xxxx.ctp) which is "populated" via blocks.

Blocks are like elements but less "formal" unless you use the "view inheritance" features.  Their markup & data get created in your scripts, in possibly multiple locations so they can be more cumbersome to debug/maintain (i.e. imagine appending markup to a block from multiple classes). They're also harder to reuse if you don't use inheritance.

Elements are more like stand-alone view files that can be used within any controller+action view or layout: all the markup is in one place and you just pass in the data.

Bottom line: if you're new to Cake, you can get by fine with just elements. View inheritance can help make views/layouts more elegant but at the price of some complexity.

Comment: thank you for detailed reply. for some months i will use elements. I will pass to blocks maybe later.  Now i'm trying to setup the usage logic of elements. I add a ctp file for each of my element, I can echo elements successfully. I'm looking for best practices. >> Should i put elements into my layout file and pass arguments to elements from my views files? >> Or should i pass arguments to elements from my controller files? >> Else it becomes complicated, doesn't it ? Controller->View->Element-Layout >> Or is it the recommended practice? Thank you

Comment: You'd put elements in layouts only if the element appears on every single page of your site. Otherwise the data should always be populated in the controller, and then in the view you pass in the data to the element.  (elements are shown via `echo` statements so they'd only make sense in a view/layout)